# Angular child component doesnt recognize input changes

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Hello I use parent child communication. At parent I have array which represents graph datas. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t4b8h3?file=src/app/app.component.html)

My problem is that when i change one item in array i doesn't fire child component appchanges. In demo I created example which  doesn't work. When I click update I want to update child component graph.

My child component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import { ChartService } from "./chart.service";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <highcharts-chart
      [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
      [options]="options"
      [oneToOne]="true"
      [update]="updateFromInput"
      style="width: calc(100% ); height: calc(100% - 17px); display: block;margin-top:15px;overflow: auto !important;"
    >
    </highcharts-chart>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      h1 {
        font-family: Lato;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  innerHeight: any;
  innerWidth: any;

  @Input() data: any;

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  updateFromInput = false;
  options: any;

  constructor(private chart_service: ChartService) {
    this.innerHeight = window.screen.height;
    this.innerWidth = window.screen.width;
  }

  onResize(event) {
    this.innerWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
    this.update();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.update();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.data);
    console.log("değişti");
    this.update();
  }

  update() {
    var series = this.chart_service.groupBy(
      this.data.LINE.DATA,
      "GRUP",
      "line"
    );
    var categories = this.chart_service.ArrNoDupe(
      this.data.LINE.DATA.map(x => x.NAME)
    );
    let isLegend = series.length > 1 ? true : false;
    var size = this.innerWidth / (12 / this.data.SIZE) - 30;
    if (this.innerWidth <= 992) {
      size = this.innerWidth - 30;
    }
    this.options = {
      title: { enabled: false, text: "" },
      credits: { enabled: false },
      legend: { enabled: true },
      tooltip: { hideDelay: 0, outside: true, shared: true },
      plotOptions: {
        line: { dataLabels: { enabled: !isLegend }, enableMouseTracking: true }
      },
      yAxis: { title: { enabled: false } },
      xAxis: { categories: categories },
      series: series
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After helpful answer above I assing firstly index to variable then updated with using index  like below code [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyvkpy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
 let index=this.reports.findIndex( x => x.CHART_ITEM_ID == id ); 
  this.reports[index]= ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In your app.component.ts:

```
filter(id) {
    this.reports.filter(x => x.ID == id)[0] = {
      ID: 3233.0,
    ...
   }
}
```

`Array.prototype.filter` does not mutate the given array, but returns a new array with the filtered properties.
You must reassign this value to make the Angular change detection detect this new array:

```
filter(id) {
    this.reports = this.reports.filter(x => x.ID == id)[0] = {
      ID: 3233.0,
    ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are three mistakes in your code:

- Your `@Input()` getter/setter are switched

```
@Input() set data(data: any) {
  this._param = data;
}

get data(): any {
  return this._param;
}
```

- Your filter actually does not filter anything (at least as far as I see from the data)
- Your `*ngFor` needs to be notified, that your data has changed - for that you could implement the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook and assign the latest value from the `SimpleChanges` of your reports to the member variable reports

Comment: in filter just graph data is changing as demo only I changed one point. But in child it does not enter ngOnChanges.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as `@code-gorilla` mentioned, it is not working because you are not mutating the `reports` array so the changes are not detected = your chart is not updated.

After modifying your code so it will mutate the `reports` I was able to make it working, you can find more details in the demo I attached below.

```js
  filter(id) {
    const updatedReport = (this.reports.filter(
      x => x.CHART_ITEM_ID == id
    )[0] = { ... } 
    });

    this.reports[0] = updatedReport;
  }
```

**Live demo:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7yr5qg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

In general, `OnChanges` is fired when the data object source has changed, but not if the data has been mutated. In order for an array to cause `OnChanges` to be called, it must be updated in an immutable fashion.
In [this article example](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/lets-clear-up-the-confusion-around-the-slice-splice-split-methods-in-javascript-8ba3266c29ae/), slice is a *immutable function* - meaning it does not change the original array, whereas splice is a *mutable* function- meaning it changes the original array.

So in your example, in order for onChanges to be called, you would need to use an immutable function like `map` instead of `filter`.

In your specific case, it looks like you do not really want to use `filter`, since you just need the first element that matches the predicate. You should really use `find` instead.
have a separate property of `report`, then have your function call `report = this.reports.find(x => x.CHART_ITEM_ID == id)` , and bind `report` to the child